# Mixed Scaled and ordinary coordinates in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, plot, wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to specify a position in terms of Scaled coordinates in one direction and use the ordinary coordinates from my data points in the other direction on the plot?  In other words, I want to specify a position, where the x coordinate is an ordinary coordinate and will change position in the plot if the plot range is changed, but the y coordinate is Scaled coordinate and will remain at a fixed height relative to the plot.

Comment: Is this for a list plot, or are you using Graphics objects?

Comment: I'm trying to use the function "Scaled" within a Graphics object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bit late in coming, but is this what you are looking for?

```
data = {{1, 0.5}, {2, 0.7}, {3, 0.4}, {4, 0.2}};
Graphics[
  Line[data /. {x_, y_} :> Scaled[{0, y}, {x, 0}]],
  Axes -> True,
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 100}},
  AspectRatio -> Full
]
```

Comment: This is indeed what I'm looking for.  Fine trick!  Thank you.